# How can I send data to the client after use readdir inside a readdir

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise, readdir

I need read a folder called 'curvas'. A lot of folders are inside 'curvas' and i'm using readdir to get them. After get the folders inside 'curvas', i'm doing a foreach and using readdir to list the files (files inside the folders that is inside 'curvas').

The problem is that i can only access the variable inside the internal readdir (i tested with console.log).

Q: How can I access this variables and respond to the client with res. ?

Here's how far I came:

```
exports.getInserted = async function (req, res) {

    var teste = await getFilesNames(); // HERE I NEED TO GET THIS FILES NAMES WITH FOLDERS
    console.log(teste); // AND THEM PASSING TO THE CLIENT WITH RES.SEND()

};

function getFilesNames() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const chartFolder = './curvas/';
        var fileNames = [];

        fs.readdir(chartFolder, (err, folders) => {

            if (err) {
                reject(new Error("Erro ao ler os arquivos."));
            }
            folders.forEach(folder => {
                fs.readdir(chartFolder + folder, (err, files) => {
                    fileNames = files;
                    console.log(files) // ----- HERE I CAN SEE ALL FILES AND LIST WITH THEIR FOLDERS.
                });
            });
            // I NEED USE resolve(fileNames) HERE, BUT IS EMPTY!!
        });
    });
};
```

Thank you!

[EDIT]

**Solution:** Guided by @omarwaleed

```
    exports.getInserted = async function (req, res) {

    // Envia os arquivos das pastas de curvas para o cliente.
    var data = await getFilesNames();
    res.status(200).send(data);

};

function getFilesNames() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const chartFolder = './curvas/';

        // take care. I've turned it into an async function here
        fs.readdir(chartFolder, async (err, folders) => {

            if (err) {
                reject(new Error("Erro ao ler os arquivos."));
            }
            let promiseArray = [];
            folders.forEach(folder => {
                promiseArray.push(
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.readdir(chartFolder + folder, (err, files) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve({
                            folder: folder,
                            files: files
                        });
                    }))
                )
            });
            let results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
            resolve(results)
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using resolve in place of the comment `// I NEED USE resolve(fileNames) HERE, BUT IS EMPTY!!` will result in an undefined resolve statement since the second `fs.readdir` will run asynchronously which means that the directory will be read AFTER your code resolves. To solve this problem I advise you to wrap fs.readdir with promises where you can await the reading of all files and resolve the response
Here's how your function will look like

```
function getFilesNames() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const chartFolder = './curvas/';
        var fileNames = [];

        // take care. I've turned it into an async function here
        fs.readdir(chartFolder, async (err, folders) => {

            if (err) {
                reject(new Error("Erro ao ler os arquivos."));
            }
            let promiseArray = [];
            folders.forEach( folder => {
            promiseArray.push(
              new Promise((resolve, reject)=>fs.readdir(chartFolder + folder, (err, files)=>{
                if(err){
                  reject(err)
                }
                resolve(files)
              }))
            )
        });
        let results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
            resolve(results)
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: First of all, thank you! It works. The only thing that i changed was 'promiseArray.push(fs.readdirSync(chartFolder + folder )). 

I changed to Synchronous and delete the close brackets '}' 

Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure :) by the way, I do advice you against using sync functions since they block the event loop from executing and therefore your server will not be able to handle multiple requests if one of them is reading synchronously

Comment: Oh, ok. But, how can I use this function with Async readdir? It's causes an error with that close brackets

Comment: I fixed the answer and removed the bracket that might have been the problem for the syntax error :)
as for using async readdir you simply use readdir without providing a callback. That way, fs-extra understands that you would like to return a promise instead of running a callback when execution is done

Comment: I tried like this: 
promiseArray.push({
                    folder: folder,
                    files: fs.readdir(chartFolder + folder)
                });

But the files return empty

Comment: don't add curly brackets inside the push just remove them and it will work ;)

Comment: Sorry for bother you, but it doesn't. I tried without the brackets and the return is empty. If i use readdirSync, with or without brackets, works.

Comment: I did a small mistake. fs-extra does promisify most of fs functions but not readdir. I'll post an updated solution. This is why it returns undefined since readdir has no promise version. My bad :D I'll correct it in a bit ;)

Comment: Still returning empty :(

Comment: terribly sorry for that. I forgot a couple normal braces and also I forgot to wrap the promiseArray variable with a Promise.all() to await all promises. Please try it again. It should work like a charm. Sorry for all the mistakes. I have updated the answer again

Comment: Works like a charm